# Лицензия подключаемой библиотеки

Tags: лицензирование, bsd

С лицензиями сталкиваюсь первый раз. Извините, если вопрос покажется банальным, но каких то четких ответов я так и не нашел.

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я хочу использовать в своей проекте и подключить библиотеку, которая "лицензируется BSD и GPLv2", то, что это в итоге значит в данным контексте в случае GPLv2:

-Я распространяю скомпилированный код, то есть бинарные файлы.

-Если я включаю данную библиотеку в своей код, должен ли я представлять весь своей исходный код по первому требованию любого человека ?

-Возможно ли распространение бинарных файлов использующих данную библиотеку, только выборочным людям и за определенную плату ?

Comment: Это значит, что берите любую из этих двух лицензий на свой вкус, а на другую лицензию просто не обращайте внимания

Comment: @andreymal, Спасибо. А если применить мои вопросы к лицензии GPLv2, то какие ответы на них можно дать ? Я почитал комментарии и описание этой лицензии до в итоге так и не понял.

Comment: GPL обязывает вас предоставлять исходный код, но никто не запрещает продавать программу только избранным людям. Однако имейте в виду, что по условиям той же GPL любой пользователь имеет право распространять её дальше без ограничений, то есть первый купивший у вас программу может сразу залить её исходники на какой-нибудь публичный гитхаб — так что продавать GPL-программы хоть и можно, но нет практического смысла (ну или за очень дорого, чтобы людям было слишком жалко сливать купленные исходники)

Comment: Но можно схитрить и выкинуть GPL-библиотеку в отдельный процесс и взаимодействовать с этим процессом только через какое-нибудь межпроцессное взаимодействие — тогда GPL-код не будет линковаться с вашей собственной программой и вы будете обязаны отдавать GPL-код только для этого отдельного процесса, а с вашей основной программой можно будет делать что угодно

Comment: @andreymal, еще раз Спасибо. Но версий GPL же целых три шутку: GPL, GPL2 и GPL3 и все три версии говорят о том, что, если в моем коде используется одна из библиотек под GPLv2, то я должен выложить Весь свой исходный код ? Грубо говоря условно - в проекте предположим миллион строк собственного кода, я добавляю в проект сторонню библиотеку из всего 100 строк под лицензией GPL2  и с этого момента - я обязан предоставить ВЕСЬ свой код ?

Comment: Ага, в этом основной смысл GPL https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ru.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

Comment: @andreymal, вот блин, Спасибо, что объяснили.

Comment: @andreymal, позвольте еще вопрос: почитал про лицензию BSD, которая в основном состоит из указания авторских прав, отказ от ответственности и что нельзя утверждать, что это это ПО написано мной, НО ничего не сказано про открытие Исходного кода. Если так, то зачем в рамках одной библиотеки используется, как я понимаю две противоположные по смыслу лицензии ? Одна из которых обязывает открывать Исходный код, а другая не требует этого ?

Comment: Не знаю. Эта библиотека есть где-то в открытом доступе, чтобы можно было почитать её условия напрямую, а не в вашем пересказе?

Comment: @andreymal, да конечно - этой фейсбучная библиотека: https://github.com/facebook/zstd

Comment: На английском Stack Overflow тоже не понимают зачем так сделано https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/6276

Comment: А ещё докапываются до союза «и» вместо «или» https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/2663

Comment: А ещё вот тут автор zstd и сотрудник фейсбука (запрещённой в РФ организации) явно подтверждает, что можно просто взять BSD и не париться https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/1611

Comment: @andreymal,Спасибо огромное! Интересно, а  использование кода фейсбучный библиотек, тоже запрещено на территории РФ ? (шутка)

Comment: Шутки шутками, а я после своего комментария чёт засомневался https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62614903#62614903

Comment: Переходите на сторону пиратов, плюньте на все это лицензии и запреты

Comment: @avp, а Вы так поступаете ? Все равно рано или поздно пират оказывается на виселице :)

Comment: @Optimus1, расскажите это потомкам Генри Моргана -)